# Populating dropdown menu in separate div from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu, pagination

Populating dropdown menu from php in separate div

I have a function search() that uses ajax and passes a number of values/variables through to php like colour, itemtype etc as 'ajax_data'.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'phpmysql.php',
        data: ajax_data,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#searchresults').html(data);
        }
    }).error(function() {
        alert ('An error occurred');
    });
```

Search results are then populated dynamically into #searchresults.

I have a dropdown menu (#pagemenu) that I want to dynamically display the page numbers of the current search, for example if there are 10 pages of results display options from 1 to 10 on dropdown.

I have worked out the 'results per page' and 'number of total pages' in php and set them to $per_page and $totalpages.

```
//forloop listing number of pages in dropdown
    for ($x=1; $x<=$totalpages; $x++) {
    echo "<option value=".$x.">".$x."</option>";
    }
```

So the search results are loaded into #searchresults but how would I go about loading the above for loop into the #pagemenu dropdown in a separate div? The only way I can currently think of doing it is by writing the php for the dropdown and forloop in the main page then using session variables to link to php file but not sure if this is a good idea. Any advice is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: really not clear what your specific issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking to your specific question, which involves creating the drop down in the server and return it in the AJAX response, you seem to need to return two things in said response: the data and the pagination options.

One thing that you could do is to return a Json object containing both things, so you could do something like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#searchresults').html(data.result);
    $('#pagemnu').html(data.options);
}
```

One of the ways to can achieve this from the client side is to add the `dataType` to `json`, so `data` is parsed to an object and its ready to be used as such:

```
$.ajax({

    dataType: 'json',

    url: 'phpmysql.php',
    data: ajax_data,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#searchresults').html(data.result);
        $('#pagemnu').html(data.options);
    }
}).error(function() {
        alert ('An error occurred');
});
```

In the server side, you would populate an array with both results and return it as JSON:

```
$result = array();
...
$result['searchResult'] = $theSearchResult;

$optionsHtml = '';
for ($x=1; $x<=$totalpages; $x++) {
    $optionsHtml .= "<option value=".$x.">".$x."</option>";
}
$result['options'] = $optionsHtml;

...

echo json_encode( $result );
```